# jQuery.get only send parameter ajaxRequest=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a weird problem I stumbled upon today. Sending data with jQuery.get like this:

```
 $.get( "ajax_articles.inc.php", 
        'site=article&operation=newArticle', 
        function() { /* ... */ }, 'html' );
```

results in an ajax-Requestlike this:

```
http://localhost/website/ajax_articles.inc.php?ajaxRequest=true&_=1471969804080
```

However, if the same request looks like this:

```
$.get( "ajax_articles.inc.php", 
       {site : 'article', operation: 'newArticle' }, 
       function() { /* ... */}, 'html' );
```

I get the desired request:

```
http://localhost/website/ajax_articles.inc.php?site=article&operation=newArticle&ajaxRequest=true&_=1471970652894
```

The first request type worked for months. It's in our code dozens of times. Today it stopped working and I do have that problem even if I type those lines into the console. Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

**Edit:**

Wo do have a `$.ajaxSetup()` in our code that looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache    : false,
    dataType : 'html'
});
```

Comment: first one looks just like the second one, I pasted it into the console and I see `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106819/ajax_articles.inc.php?site=article&operation=newArticle".` Do you have other code running that is setting the other parameters?

Comment: What does the Accept-Type header look like on both requests. `{}` will serialize into JSON and set an Accept-Type. Im not sure if that occurs with the string

Comment: Did you update something?, because on my side they do the same... and bring the same content.

Comment: @epascarello Same here. We haven't messed around with those jQuery-functions. The XHR-Trace looks exactly the same as on stackoverflow.

@MattSizzle `Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01` for both.

Comment: Search your code base for `$.ajaxSetup()`

Comment: you may have more than one ajaxsetup. Look for "processData: false"